# Where can I find sympy code for reference

Tags: sympy

Some times I found it hard to find out how to write out sympy code.

For example: How to draw out cos(x)'s several series expansions in one graph.

> After a long time trying, I made it:

```py
from sympy.abc import *
from sympy import *
plot(*Array(cos(x).series(n=m).removeO() for m in [4, 6, 8]),
     cos(x), (x, -2 * pi, 2 * pi),
     ylim=(-1.5, 1.5))
```

The introduction of these `removeO(),Array,ylim` scatter in different places. Which is not so easy to gather.

And the usage of `*` is hard to find in document.

So I find that the document maybe is not so suitable for a totally newer to sympy. Maybe a collection of examples will have better effects? In which an example will gather many details together instead of just introduce one function. So where can I find a place like that?

> I know I can search on this site :) , but detailed examples can also save much times for user.

Comment: You might start by reading through the tutorials in the doc directory. Even though they won't answer your specific question you will get an idea how Python/SymPy work. The use of `*` to unpack an iterable is a Python feature, for example. I don't see `removeO` used in a docstring and that is something that should be remedied.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I wrote a project called [PyF1](https://github.com/wuyudi/PyF1) which is still in the initial stage.

All the examples are from Mathematica's help manual.

Here are some pictures of it.

[image]

[image]

It's written in jupyter, which means we can watch it online.

Because I don't have much time， so the update of this manual will be much slow.

> Until now , I have written many funcitons. Which is kind of enough.